# XML parsing in python Pandas get a complete block of tags in one row

Tags: python, xml, pandas, lxml

Hi I can convert my xml file to pandas dataframe. But challenge i have is i am not getting records in proper row, lets say we have a set of tag in xml which is getting repeated for eg. 4 times, and it has multiple child node which should be columns for my dataframe, now when i am trying to read xml i want to get only 4 rows in my pandas dataframe but i am getting too many row with NaN because all the other tags lie on different level.

Edit: Just now figured out the descriprensies / differences in XML data. Mentioned one is final edited xml data
Just find out some issue with my XML data ... Updated the correct and final xml contents.

```
    Same <ns1:parenttag> is getting repeated over a xml file multiple times

  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <row:user-agents xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
  xmlns:row="http://www.row.com" 
  xmlns:ns1="http://www.ns1.com"
  xmlns:ns2="http://www.ns2.com" 
  xmlns:ns3="http://www.ns3.com"   
  xmlns:row1="http://www.row1.com" 
  xmlns:row3="http://www.row3.com" 
  xmlns:row2="http://www.row2.com" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.schemaLocation-1.4.xsd">

<row:agent1>
<row:test>
  <row2:test1>
    <row2:test2>
      <row2:test3>9999</row2:test3>
      <row2:test4>aa</row2:test4>
      <row2:test5>1</row2:test5>
    </row2:test2>
  </row2:test1>
  <row2:test6>2017</row2:test6>
</row:test>
<row:agent2>
<row3:agent3>

        <ns1:parenttag>
            <ns1:childtag1>
                <ns1:subchildtag1>
                    <ns1:indenticaltag>123</ns1:indenticaltag>
                </ns1:subchildtag1>
            </ns1:childtag1>
            <ns1:indenticaltag>456</ns1:indenticaltag>
            <ns1:childtag2>N</ns1:childtag2>
            <ns1:childtag3>0</ns1:childtag3>
            <ns1:childtag4>N</ns1:childtag4>
            <ns1:childtag5>
                <ns2:subchildtag2 attributname="abc">
                    <ns2:sub_subchildtag1>12 45</ns2:sub_subchildtag1>
                </ns2:subchildtag2>
            </ns1:childtag5>
            <ns1:childtag6>tyu</ns1:childtag6>
            <ns1:childtag7>2</ns1:childtag7>
            <ns1:childtag8> poiu</ns1:childtag8>
            <ns1:childtag9>
                <ns3:subchildtag3>345</ns3:subchildtag3>
                <ns3:subchildtag6>567</ns3:subchildtag6>

            </ns1:childtag9>
            <ns1:childtag10>N</ns1:childtag10>
            <ns1:childtag11>
                <ns3:subchildtag4>34</ns3:subchildtag4>
                <ns3:subchildtag5>abc/123</ns3:subchildtag5>
            </ns1:childtag11>
            <ns1:childtag12>
                <ns1:indenticaltag>234</ns1:indenticaltag>
            </ns1:childtag12>
        </ns1:parenttag>

</row3:agent3>
</row:agent2>
</row:agent1>
</row:user-agents>
```

Another XML which is bit different in term of parent tags:

```
        <ns1:parenttag>
            <ns1:indenticaltag>123</ns1:indenticaltag>
            <ns1:childtag2>N</ns1:childtag2>
            <ns1:childtag3>0</ns1:childtag3>
            <ns1:childtag4>N</ns1:childtag4>
            <ns1:childtag5>
                <ns2:subchildtag1 attributename0="poi">
                    <ns2:sub_subchildtag1>
                        <ns2:sub_sub_subchildtag1>
                            <ns2:sub_sub_sub_subchildtag1 attributename1="3" attributename2="17">1234</ns2:sub_sub_sub_subchildtag1>
                        </ns2:sub_sub_subchildtag1>
                    </ns2:sub_subchildtag1>
                </ns2:subchildtag1>
            </ns1:childtag5>
            <ns1:childtag6>12</ns1:childtag6>
            <ns1:childtag7> qwer</ns1:childtag7>
            <ns1:childtag8>
                <ns3:subchildtag2>456</ns3:subchildtag2>
            </ns1:childtag8>
            <ns1:childtag9>N</ns1:childtag9>
            <ns1:childtag10>
                <ns3:subchildtag3>908</ns3:subchildtag3>
                <ns3:subchildtag4>abc/123</ns3:subchildtag4>
            </ns1:childtag10>
        </ns1:parenttag>
```

I am using as of now functions suggested by Parfait in below answers:
but getting this error:

```
  i am getting ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 21 elements, new values have 22 elements erros

  Also it has issue with indenticaltag column as its of same name thrice but hierarchy is different 
  but in dataframe i am getting only one indenticaltag  column instead of 3 for example:
  parent.child.indenticaltag, parent.child.subchild.indenticaltag  and parent.child.subchild.sub_subchild.indenticaltag  etc.
```

Output dataframe is:

```
    I will parse both xmls differently using one function only. 
    Would like to parse all the tags and their attribute as column name in 
    pandas. Also the column name should be 
    parent.child.subchild.sub_sub_subchildtag and for attributes it should 
    be parent.child.subchild.sub_sub_childtag.attribute
```

Is their any better way to parse xml and get the records in proper format ? or am i missing something ?

Edit: solution worked but added some more complexities

```
  I need your help for three points if you guys can suggest some pointers:

  1) I need columns name for pandas dataframe as root.child.subchild.grandchild i am not sure how i can get it here ? as in my solution i was able to get.
  2) the descendant function is very slow is any way we can speed it up ?
  3) i have to multiple xml of same type present in one directory and i would like to generate one dataframe out of it by appending all xml results any best way to do ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a lxml's `xpath()` on the `<xs:topcol>` nodes and use lxml's `parse()` to read directly from file. The XPath loop iteratively appends to list and dictionary containers to cast to dataframe. Also, your desired output is actually not aligned to the node values:

```
import pandas as pd
from lxml import etree
import re

pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)

NSMAP = {'row': 'http://www.row.com',
         'row3': 'http://www.row3.com',
         'row1': 'http://www.row1.com',
         'xs': 'http://www.xs.com',
         'row2': 'http://www.row2.com'}

xmldata = etree.parse('RowAgent.xml')    

data = []
inner = {}
for el in xmldata.xpath('//xs:top_col', namespaces=NSMAP):
    for i in el:                                 # PARSE CHILDREN
        inner[i.tag] = i.text
        if len(i.xpath('/*')) > 0:               # PARSE GRANDCHILDREN
            for subi in i:
                inner[subi.tag] = subi.text

    data.append(inner)
    inner = {}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# REGEX TO REMOVE NAMESPACE URIs IN COL NAMES
df.columns = [re.sub(r'{.*}', '', col) for col in df.columns]
```

To parse unlimited child elements use XPath's `descendant::*`:

```
num_top_cols = len(xmldata.xpath('//xs:top_col', namespaces=NSMAP))

for i in range(1,num_top_cols+1):
    for el in xmldata.xpath('//xs:top_col[{}]/descendant::*'.format(i), namespaces=NSMAP):
        if el.text.strip()!='':                 # REMOVE EMPTY TEXT TAGS
            inner[el.tag] = el.text.strip()

    data.append(inner)
    inner = {}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Output

```
print(df)
#    col11_1       col11_2   col8_1 col8_2      col1      col10  col12  col13_1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6  col7 col9
# 0     2010  AB 20/SEC001     2010   2016  00032000  test_name    pqr   000330    N    0    3    N    I    AA    N
# 1  2016026    rty-qwe-01     2000  26000     03985      temp2  perrl  0117203    N    0    3    N    a   9AA    N
# 2     8965  147A-254-044     7896    NaN     00985       mjkl  rtyyu    45612    N    0    3    N  NaN  yuio    N
# 3    52369   ui 247/mh45  145ghg7    NaN     78965     ghyuio  trwer     9874    N    0    5    N  NaN  23rt    N
```

---

Due to the performance challenge of `descendants::*`, consider recursive calls to first traverse all descendants and then another call to capture parent/child/grandchild names for dataframe columns. Be sure to now use an `OrderedDict`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

#... same as above XML setup ... #

def recursiveParse(curr_elem, curr_inner):    
    if len(curr_elem.xpath('/*')) > 0:        
        for child_elem in curr_elem:            
            curr_inner[child_elem.tag] = child_elem.text  
            inner[i.tag] = i.text
            if child_elem.attrib is not None:                
                for attrib in child_elem.attrib: 
                    inner[attrib] = child_elem.attrib[attrib]  
            recursiveParse(child_elem, curr_inner)

    return(curr_inner)

for el in xmldata.xpath('//xs:top_col', namespaces=NSMAP):
    for i in el:        
        inner[i.tag] = i.text
        if i.attrib is not None:
            for attrib in i.attrib: 
                inner[attrib] = i.attrib[attrib]                 
        recursiveParse(i, inner)

    data.append(inner)
    inner = {}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

colnames = []
def recursiveNames(curr_elem, curr_inner, num):    
    if len(curr_elem.xpath('/*')) > 0:        
        for child_elem in curr_elem:    
            tmp = re.sub(r'{.*}', '', child_elem.tag)            
            curr_inner.append(colnames[num-1] +'.'+ tmp)
            if child_elem.attrib is not None:                
                for attrib in child_elem.attrib: 
                    curr_inner.append(curr_inner[len(curr_inner)-1] +'.'+ attrib)
            recursiveNames(child_elem, curr_inner, len(colnames))

    return(curr_inner)        

for el in xmldata.xpath('//xs:top_col[1]', namespaces=NSMAP):
    for i in el:                
        tmp = re.sub(r'{.*}', '', i.tag)
        colnames.append(tmp)
        recursiveNames(i, colnames, len(colnames))

df.columns = colnames
```

Output

```
print(df)
#        col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6  col7                  col8 col8.col8_1 col8.col8_1.sName col8.col8_2 col9      col10                 col11 col11.col11_1 col11.col11_2  col12                 col13 col13.col13_1
# 0  00032000    N    0    3    N    I    AA  \n                          2010             pqrst        2016    N  test_name  \n                            2010  AB 20/SEC001    pqr  \n                          000330
# 1     03985    N    0    3    N    a   9AA  \n                          2000               NaN       26000    N      temp2  \n                         2016026    rty-qwe-01  perrl  \n                         0117203
# 2     00985    N    0    3    N  NaN  yuio  \n                          7896               NaN         NaN    N       mjkl  \n                            8965  147A-254-044  rtyyu  \n                           45612
# 3     78965    N    0    5    N  NaN  23rt  \n                       145ghg7               NaN         NaN    N     ghyuio  \n                           52369   ui 247/mh45  trwer  \n                            9874
```

Finally, integrate this processing and original XML parsing all in a loop that iterates through all XML files in directory. However, be sure to save all dataframes in a list of dataframes, then append/stack using [`pd.concat()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html)`.

```
import # modules

dfList = []
for f in os.list.dir('/path/to/XML/files'):
   #...xml parse... (passing in f for file name in parse())
   #...dataframe build with recursive calls...

   dfList.append(df)

finaldf = pd.concat(dfList)
```

Comment: Far better than me thanks a lot !! one question how if we have grand-grand -grand children in hierarchy ? Is any standard way to traverse all the sub childs ?

Comment: Good question, see updated extension using XPath's `descendant::*` where loop through each `<xs:top_col>` by its node index and parse all its descendants.

Comment: How big is your XML? Over 1 GB? How slow is *slow* for you? Also, attributes and text are very different. Your example XML does not include attributes or attempts to parse them. Always post a true example of **actual** data.

Comment: xml is 15 MB each, but in a directory approx 1.5 k xmls. sorry for not posting correct data set now I have update the input data to have attribut, it it possible to get attribute as new column parent.child.subchild.attrib.sName?

Comment: And *slow* is relative to some people. How slow is *slow*? All appended to same dataframe? Did you want to run through over a 1,000 files in 1 min.?

Comment: See edit with recursive calls for column names and values.

Comment: Parfait, you mentioned use OrderedDict to use it i should use inner {} as inner= OrderedDict() ? correct ?

Comment: Yes as shown in code. Apologies for slow response but your question became too complex with constant spec changes. Please try to incorporate/adjust this solution into your actual.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have found the answer for above mentioned problem, Posting it so it can be helpful for others:

```
    xml_data = open('test.xml').read().encode('utf8')

    def xml2df(xml_data ):
        tree = et.parse(xml_data )
        all_records= []
        result= {}
        for el in tree.iterfind("./row:agent1/row:agent2/row3:agent3/xs:top_col/",namespaces):

            for r in el:

                if '}' in r.tag:
                    r.tag = r.tag.split('}', 1)[1] 
            for i in el.iterfind('*'):

                for s in i:

                    s.tag = s.tag.split('}',1)[1]
                    s.tag = i.tag +"."+s.tag               

                result[i.tag] = i.text

                for j in i.iterfind('*'):
                    result[j.tag] = j.text

            all_records.append(result)

            result= {}

        df = pd.DataFrame(data)
        return df
  df1 = xml2df(xml_data)
  df1
```